# MediaController inside Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, mediacontroller

I have an example of setting the Media Controller from Main Activity, but i expended my Activity with 3 fragments. Everything works except Media Controller is not displayed on my Fragment. How do I set the Media Controller with Fragment? This is from Activity.

```
private void setController() {
    controller = new MusicController(this);
    // set previous and next button listeners
    controller.setPrevNextListeners(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playNext();
        }
    }, new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playPrev();
        }
    });
    // set and show
    controller.setMediaPlayer(this);
    //getSupportFragmen

    controller.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.songList));
    controller.setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: You have to place that code inside your onCreateView() Fragment method.

Comment: Cool. I posted an answer. Please, accept it/upvote it if it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to place that code inside your `onCreateView()` `Fragment` method, so your `MusicController` is inflated in your Fragment layout.